# Trigger azure actiongroup via powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

I can retrieve my action group with the `Get-AzActionGroup` command. But I would like to activate/fire/trigger that action group via my runbook with a powershell command. Is this possible at all? And if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The command `Test-AzActionGroup` fires the Action Group, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/test-azactiongroup.

However, from my understanding, there are other limits on the number of notifications if you do it this way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/service-limits. So, you can send more voice calls this way, but depending on the scenario possibly less emails.

As the name suggests, this is [intended for tests and self-diagnosis](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-test-action-groups-in-azure-monitor/), not really production use.

Answer (score -2):

- You can create the action group using PowerShell with this command `Set-AzActionGroup`
  and here are the [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups) that have the information about managing the action group.
- Also, here are a few other links that can give you info about action groups using PowerShell.

1. https://sweetcode.io/powershell-create-azure-monitor-action-group/
2. https://wmatthyssen.com/2022/01/12/create-an-azure-monitor-action-group-with-azure-powershell/

Comment: I don't want to create an action group, but just fire it.